# Flutter Dio return object

Tags: flutter, dart, json-deserialization, dio

I'm somewhat new to Flutter and coming from .NET world.

In .NET, I have something like `httpclient.GetFromJsonAsync<User>` to perform GET and deserialize it to `User` object.
In Flutter, I'm using Dio and saw that they have similar looking method, `get<T>`. However even when I use `get<List<User>>` or `get<User>`, it always throw runtime error that it unable to cast `List<dynamic>` to `List<User>` or `Map` to `User`, despite the the code being successfully compiled.

```
final List<User> response = await Dio().get<List<User>>('urlThatReturnListOfUser');
```

Is there a better way or package to deserialize dynamic/map to object?

The best way I found so far is using Json_Serializable, but even then, I still have to write things like

```
final List<User> weathers = (response.data as List)
          .map((e) => User.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList();
```

every time I call the API. Or is this my best bet at the moment? Or did I using Dio wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Such a library would require using runtime reflection, which is disabled in Flutter. Runtime reflection interferes with tree shaking, which Dart has supported for quite a long time. With tree shaking, you can “shake off” unused code from your release builds. This optimizes the app’s size significantly.

> Since reflection makes all code implicitly used by default, it makes tree shaking difficult. The tools cannot know what parts are unused at runtime, so the redundant code is hard to strip away. App sizes cannot be easily optimized when using reflection.

> Although you cannot use runtime reflection with Flutter, some libraries give you similarly easy-to-use APIs but are based on code generation instead. This approach is covered in more detail in the code generation libraries section.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Unfortunately, you are using the most accurate way of deserializing at the moment.